# HTML "a" tags with identically named target keeps opening new windows

Tags: html

I thought that by putting identical names on the `target=` attribute of links I would be making all such links open in the same named browser window or tab. That seems not to be the case, at least in Chrome or Firefox. Instead, repeated clicks on such links create another new browser tab with every click. How can I direct such links to an already existing named window?

Comment: Can you please post example code or even a code snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: set your target attribute value to _self and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to set it to _self. I want to keep the main page open while several other pages all open in the same (different) window or tab.

Comment: Sample code might look like this:

<html><body>
Some stuff... blah blah blah.
<a href="help1.html" target="helpwindow">Help 1</a>
<a href="help2.html" target="helpwindow">Help 2</a>
<a href="help3.html" target="helpwindow">Help 3</a>
</body></html>

The idea is that clicking any of the "help" links should open the document in the same "helpwindow" window or tab, not create new tabs for each one - while the original document stays in its original window.

Comment: What actually happens with code like this is that each click on one of the links opens another new tab/window, even though they all are directed to the same named window.

Comment: This question was Asked 5 years, 7 months ago now.  I still have this problem on all of Chrome, Firefox and Edge? How can that be? Is it because they are all based on the same  base-implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this behavior too. It was happening because the document loaded into the target window (A URL to a Salesforce page) was changing the name of its window via the window.name property. So the next time the browser tried to load a URL into window with the target name, it couldn't find that window, so it opened a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be  a "bug" that still lives on at least in Firefox, Chrome and Edge, the common browsers. I found the following not so easy to understand note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open :

" ...  This functionality is not valid for all browsers and more with variable conditions. Firefox (50.0.1) functions as described: from the same domain+port reopen with same name will access the previously created window. Google Chrome (55.0.2883.87 m ) on the other hand will do it only from the same parent (as if the window was created dependent, which is the "opener"). This is a wide limitation and generates unbelievable complexity of development. ..."

So I think we can safely say that this feature does not work reliably across browsers, still.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to previous answers:

If you are also using the `rel="noreferrer"` attribute value, Chrome 87.0.4280.88 will open a new tab even if one with that target already exists.

I got rid of this attribute altogether and witnessed a return to the expected behaviour. A unique `target=` value will not cause a new tab to be created unnecessarily, but will activate a previous tab with that target value.

Note that Firefox (a venerable v79.0) does not have this problem with `rel="noreferrer"` and will reuse the tab for the same target.

Answer (score -1):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp, you can set `target=""` to:

1. _blank:

    Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
2. _self:

    Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
3. _parent:

    Opens the linked document in the parent frame
4. _top:

    Opens the linked document in the full body of the window

OR (what you're looking for)

5. framename:

    Opens the linked document in a named frame

Comment: What I'm finding is that #5 acts exactly the same as #1. That is, giving a framename always opens the linked document in a new window or tab, even if there is already an existing window or tab that was previously opened with the same framename.

Comment: This is not an answer, because David knows it, I guess, and asking why #5 isn't working..